# Download files file_put_contents with progress

Tags: php, callback, file-put-contents

I try to write code with download file and return status (downloaded bytes).
To download file I use file_put_contents and it's work.

```
function downloadLink($link,$destination)
{
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_params($ctx, array("notification" => "stream_notification_callback"));
    $mb_download = file_put_contents($destination, fopen($link, 'r'),null,$ctx);
    return $mb_download;
}

function stream_notification_callback($notification_code, $severity, $message, $message_code, $bytes_transferred, $bytes_max) {
    file_put_contents( 'progress.txt', '' );
    $fp = fopen('progress.txt', 'a' );
    fputs( $fp,$bytes_transferred);
    fclose( $fp );
    echo 1;
}
```

It's my functions. I have problem to use callback function because all function is inside the same class. Now stream_notification_callback is not use. I try change declaration to

```
stream_context_set_params($ctx, array("notification" => "$this->stream_notification_callback()"));
```

Or

```
stream_context_set_params($ctx, array("notification" => $this->stream_notification_callback()));
```

But it's not working.

Comment: does it show any errors?

Comment: Your calback syntax is wrong. `"$this->stream_notification_callback()"` should be `[$this, 'stream_notification_callback']`

Comment: Have you checked [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-params.php), as there mentioned param names
"notification" - Name of user-defined callback function to be called whenever a stream triggers a notification.

Comment: but this solution not working to. In stream_notification_callback I create file  with log. But this solution doesn't run function stream_notification_callback because file is not created and echo not write sth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with

```
stream_context_set_params($ctx, array(
    "notification" => array($this, 'stream_notification_callback')
));
```

Comment: It's not work... I use echo to check if program is inside stream_notification_callback but message is empty.

Answer (score 0):

After the implementation of what Matei Mihai said, it actually still does not work because the context is used in the `file_put_contents()` function while it should be used in the `fopen()` function.

Therefore this:

```
$mb_download = file_put_contents($destination, fopen($link, 'r'),null,$ctx);
```

Should actually be this:

```
$mb_download = file_put_contents( $destination, fopen( $link, 'r', null, $ctx) );
```

And then it would work!