# php - notification in stream_context_set_params() not called

Tags: php, wordpress, fopen, file-put-contents

I am using this code in php (Wordpress) to check for download progress:

```
// Create context
$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_params( $context, [ 'notification' => 'my_stream_notification_callback' ] );

// Declare progress function
function my_stream_notification_callback($notification_code, $severity, $message, $message_code, $bytes_transferred, $bytes_max) {
    print_r(func_get_args());
}

// Call download
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
file_put_contents( $wp_upload_dir['basedir'] . '/contact.htm', fopen( 'http://php.net/contact', 'r' ), null, $context );
```

The code does download the file successfully in the `/wp-content/uploads/` folder, but does not print any notification / progress.

I tried also by writing to `error_log()` in the `my_stream_notification_callback()` function but it does not write anything there and the `debug.log` file is empty. Which means the notification callback is not being called at all.

Anyone has any idea why this would happen?

Here is a question with similar code but different problem:
[Download files file_put_contents with progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292472/download-files-file-put-contents-with-progress)
Evidently, the code works for him after the callback function was fixed for a class/object method function. While I am trying a simpler callback function that should definitely work.

Any ideas?

**-- EDIT --**

I found an example on php.net here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-notification-callback.php

I used that example and it seems to work.

See the code I used (a bit changed from the example):

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_params( $ctx, [
    "notification" => function ( $notification_code, $severity, $message, $message_code, $bytes_transferred, $bytes_max ) {
        print_r(func_get_args());
    },
] );

file_get_contents( "http://php.net/contact", false, $ctx );
```

Now this code works and prints out the progress notifications:

Does it mean that `file_put_contents()` or `fopen()` has problems with context/notifications that `file_get_contents()` do not have?

**--EDIT--**

Here is the change what actually works:

```
file_put_contents( $wp_upload_dir['basedir'] . '/contact.htm', fopen( 'http://php.net/contact', 'r', null, $context ) );
```

Means, instead of applying $context to `file_put_contents()` we apply it to `fopen()` call and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in the documentation at http://php.net/stream_context_set_params, the `notification` callback is only triggered for `ftp` and `http` connections. As you use it to write something to a local directory (through another protocol), it's pretty obvious why the callback is never called.

Comment: Thanks Nico for your answer. But in this SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292472/download-files-file-put-contents-with-progress) the user had it working for file_put_content(), is it some difference of php settings/config?

Comment: Are you sure about this? He claims multiple times that all approaches are not working

Comment: I think you are right, the guy has accepted the answer which makes it feel like his problem is solved. But the code actually does not work. I have made a change in my code a little and it works. The idea is what you said that context is applied to file writing, while it should be applied to file reading part. Let me update my question with the fix.